# C# - Array of Jagged Array

Tags: c#, arrays, geojson, jagged-arrays

How to initialize and allocate array of jagged array? I am trying to create Geojson Polygon coordinates structure (with no holes) like the example geojson below using c# objects. My code able to generate the json which using jagged array and missing some bracket next to "coordinates": , but want that json like the example geojson, which can be possible using array of jagged array. Code example for array of jagged array would be appreciated.

*My code generated*

```
{ "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": 
          [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]

    }
```

*Example Geojson Polygon*

```
{ "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
      ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do they _have_ to be arrays? A better solution would be to create a `Coordinates` class that extends `List<List<System.Drawing.PointF>>`.

Comment: Hi, This would also work only difference is the List type instead of arrays, also i think jagged arrays are good performers when allocating than List.

Comment: Sure, but since you're already doing something that's inherently slow (serialization), that's not your greatest concern.

Answer (score 0):

Array of jagged arrays:

```
double[][][] coordinates = 
            {
                new double[][]
                    {
                        new double[] {1, 3, 5, 7, 9},
                        new double[] {0, 2, 4, 6},
                        new double[] {11, 22}
                    }
            };
```

But, in my opinion, your first code sample seems to do the job. Are you sure you need this?

Actually, why not an array of `GeoPoint`, where a `GeoPoint` holds two `double`s and is mapped to a json array when serialized?